# cypress 12 docker throw error socket_posix.cc(93)] CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol (97)

Tags: docker, cypress, centos7, cypress-component-test-runner

I upgraded my cypress version from  `cypress 8` to `cypress 12`.
I am executing all my test cases on jenkins server OS `centos 7` using base image `cypress/base:16.13.0`.

When I executed all the test cases on my local `window 10` using same docker image `cypress/base:16.13.0` and  `"cypress": "^12.3.0",`All works perfectly good.

BUT when I trying to run the same project on Jenkins server `centos 7` OS, throw an error
`[476:0123/104731.525262:ERROR:socket_posix.cc(93)] CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol (97)`

[image]

Note : When I executed the same package (test cases) on `cypress 8` all works good.
Kindly suggest me how to fix this?

**cypress.config.js** file :

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
const createBundler = require('@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor');
const addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin =
  require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin;
const createEsbuildPlugin =
  require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild').createEsbuildPlugin;



module.exports = defineConfig({
  defaultCommandTimeout: 5000,
  numTestsKeptInMemory: 0,
  viewportWidth: 1360,
  viewportHeight: 768,
  env: {
    username: 'xxxx',
    password: '',
  },
  "retries": 1, 
  "video": false,
  e2e: {
     // Integrate @bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor plugin.
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const bundler = createBundler({
        plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
      });

      // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
      on('file:preprocessor', bundler);
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

      return config;
    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.feature',
  },
});
```

**Package.json**

```
   "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^15.1.0",
    "@deepakvishwakarma/cucumber-json-formatter": "^0.0.3",
    "cypress": "^12.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.1.5",
    "cypress-xpath": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.js",
    "commonPath": "cypress/e2e/common/**/*.cy.js",
    "filterSpecs": true,
    "omitFiltered": true,
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
    "json": {
      "enabled": true,
      "output": "cypress/cucumber_report/log.json",
      "formatter": "node",
      "args": [
        "./node_modules/@deepakvishwakarma/cucumber-json-formatter/lib/main.js"
      ]
    },
    "cucumberJson": {
      "generate": true,
      "outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber_report",
      "filePrefix": "",
      "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find out the solution? Having a similar problem.

Comment: @jktravis, I tried lot but not yet